# How to get value from array in android?

Tags: android, arrays, match

I am building an Android application where user is entering a value like
name and emailId, this value is parsed to an URL and in response I get
user ID that is primary key of that user.

I get ID in the form of an array form with successfully message. Like
this - `{"message" : "succefull", "userID":"34341390ssvjsv"}`.

Now I need to save this userID in an string from this array.

How can store this ID "34341390ssvjsv" in a string?

Here is code -

```
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";

        // Create an array
        // public String postData() {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String URl = "http://url/api/user";
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URl);
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    3);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            inputStream  = response.getEntity().getContent();

            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

            return result;

    }


     private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new    
         InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            String result = "";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                result += line;

            inputStream.close();
            return result;

        }   



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

In this above code on toast result I get  {"message" : "succefull", "userID":"34341390ssvjsv"}

Comment: `String example = "34341390ssvjsv"`

Comment: Thanks @m0skit0 I had edit my question please help I am new to android

Comment: What you're receiving is a JSON string, check that.

Comment: I am getting {"message" : "succefull", "userID":"34341390ssvjsv"} as result now I need only userID from it in an different string so that I can save it in shared preferences

Comment: Yes. That's a JSON string. Look for libraries to process such strings. If you don't want to use JSON libraries, then use `indexOf` and `substring` methods to get that string.

Comment: try this:  String myJSONString = "{'message' : 'succefull', 'userID':'34341390ssvjsv'}";
JsonObject jobj = new Gson().fromJson(myJSONString, JsonObject.class);

String id= jobj.get("userID").toString();

Comment: @m0skit0 Thanks can you please tell me how can I use indexOf and substring to do this....\

Comment: @Rami It is showing error - JsonObject cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: No. Try something yourself and then show us what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: you must add json.jar to your project

Comment: @Rami thanks! can you please give any link ?

Comment: Extract it to get the Jar http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java/java-json.jar.zip

Comment: @Rami added still error

Comment: @m0skit0 I had searched a lot about indexvalue and substring but did not get use full thing's that work in my case.. PLease can you suggest something

Comment: Oh yeah, I see how you've searched...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code - 
String re = result.substring(37,3);